# Startup Activity Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, media

I have a simple Activity called StartupActivity that plays on startup of my application and opens up MainActivity in an intent. I noticed that if I change the manifest to open directly to MainActivity then my app uses 7mb or more less RAM on MainActivity. I believe this is a memory leak. I cannot find it though, could someone help me out

```
 public class StartupActivity extends Activity {

private MediaManager mp;
private CountDownTimer time;
private boolean activityHasExited;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);
    activityHasExited=false;

    mp = new MediaManager();
    mp.playSoundClip(this,R.raw.intro);
    //display the logo 
    time = new CountDownTimer(4000,1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        } 

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            if(!activityHasExited){
                Intent i= new Intent(StartupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                time=null;
                StartupActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
   }.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    if(time!=null){
        time.cancel();
        time=null;
    }
    mp.stop();
    activityHasExited=true;
}
 }
```

Support class:

```
 //source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254870/play-a-sound-from-res-raw
 public class MediaManager {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

public void stop() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void playSoundClip(Context c, int rid) {
    stop();

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, rid);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            stop();
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
 }
```

Edit: By changing onDestroy to onStop (as per 
ChallengeAccepted's or Simon's suggestion) the activity will finish if the user hits home before the countdown ends, which is good! I'm still seeing more memory usage when I include the intro activity than when I don't though. Since this activity is a one time usage my goal is to completely clean up and keep my app as slim as possible.

Comment: Can not see leak in your code, may be you can set breakpoint in onDestroy, and check if the startUp activity is destroied after you start the MainActivity.

Comment: `onDestroy()` will only be useful if you explicitly call `finish()` or otherwise remove the activity from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a memory leak. If you open an Activity A and then an Activity B, the first one will continue in memory until Android needs memory or Android considers that that Activity A potentially won't be open again. Further more, in your case the activity A is playing something which will consume more than an usual activity.

Comment: It may not be a strictly defined memory leak, but it won't ever be opened again during the app's lifespan so in my mind it should be completely cleaned up without waiting for Android. How does Android determine the potential for it to be opened again.

Comment: It is long to explain :( . Here you can see the details of the activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Thank you! For the current issue, is there any way I can manually clean up this startup activity so that it doesn't continue to use resources after its function has been served?

Comment: You can call finish() when you don't want use the activity again but only Android will decide if remove it from memory or not

Answer (score 0):

Your onDestroy method and even the onStop method are never guarenteed to be called that is why Google recommends we use onPause since that is guarenteed to be called.

You can read more about the android lifecycle by clicking [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Comment: hey great suggestion! It still doesn't completely clean up the activity though...