# Android MediaPlayer not playing

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Following problem: I just want to play a small `.wav` file with a mediaplayer in Android. The `.wav` file is in the `raw` directory. I want to start the sound from the MainActivity. This is how I play the sound:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
mp.start();
```

As soon as I call `mp.start()` I get following errorsin my LogCat:

```
01-05 11:07:17.729 19960-19960/com.example.simplesound E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
01-05 11:07:17.729 19960-19960/com.example.simplesound E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
01-05 11:07:17.862 19960-19960/com.example.simplesound D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
01-05 11:07:17.925 19960-21184/com.example.simplesound E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
01-05 11:07:17.926 19960-19960/com.example.simplesound E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Anyone knows how tho fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this,  R.raw.zindgivalaaop);
player.setVolume(50,50);
player.start();

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     player.stop();
     player.release();
}
```

try passing class context instead `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: try playing some other file.

Comment: Okay wow. Tried another sound file downloaded from internet and voila it works! Thanks! Don't know what's wrong with my files. You know any way to fix that?

Comment: i am not sure..but try .mp3 file if you can

Comment: my application is getting crashed if i pass getApplicationContext

Comment: please pass class' context and not the application context.

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below which answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254870/play-a-sound-from-res-raw). It'll work like a charm.

```
package com.example.hellomoon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class AudioPlayer {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

public void stop() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void play(Context c, int rid) {
    stop();

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, rid);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            stop();
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but even that doesn't work for me :( Maybe it's caused by my API Level? I'm running it on Android 7.1 (API 25)

Comment: Then it means you have a problem on your sound file. Try to use another raw file.

Comment: Okay wow. Tried another sound file downloaded from internet and voila it works! Thanks! Don't know what's wrong with my files. You know any way to fix that?

Comment: Don't know really, thanks for not choosing best answer, although I answered first :D

Comment: This is wrong. On completion `release()` will be called and when play() for a second time `Stop()-->release()` will be called again which causes an error. (see the state machine diagram for android media player)

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [Playing short .wav files - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883883/playing-short-wav-files-android)

SoundPool is the best way to play short .wav(2-3 sec.) file

For  more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: Yes, I will try this. I thought `MediaPlayer` is the more easy one but since it doesn't work I'll have to use `SoundPool` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think your MediaPlayer is working. Check the device 'Media volume' in settings. `JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0` this message comes when the device 'Media volume' set to zero.